# Vue2 - pushing string to array just replaces existing string rather than adding it

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to add/remove strings from a local data array in a method and my logic always ends up with the array always having only a single string, that being the one passed to the updateIdArr method.

Even if I remove the `else` // remove portion the push never "ads" to the array. The array only ever has 1 string, the last value pushed.

What am I missing?

```
data() {
  return {
    idArr: [],
  }
},
methods: {
  updateIdArr(show) {
    if (!this.idArr.includes(show._id)) {
      // add
      this.idArr.push(show._id);
    } else {
      // remove
      this.idArr = this.idArr.filter((id) => id !== show._id);
    }
    console.log(this.idArr); 
    // always has *only* the most recent value
    // e.g. ['01GDKN93GP6Q0QDBVQ3W9BDT6D', __ob__: Observer]
  },
}
```

Comment: Not super familiar with vue but in react this is a common symptom of [stale state](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-every-react-developer-should-know-about-state/#:~:text=What%20is%20stale%20state%20in,variable%20from%20an%20outer%20scope.)

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: stupid human error

Each local data value was in a separate component. I need to emit to the parent and maintain the array there.

Answer (score 0):

Your `remove` method is not doing anything as, unlike `push`, `filter` does not modify the array and instead returns a new one:

`this.idArr = this.idArr.filter((id) => id !== show._id);`

Not sure if that would break whatever this `__ob__: Observer` thing is doing though, if so you may need to filter it in-place using a for loop or something.

Comment: yeah, I fixed that and the remove does remove the string now, but adding new strings never actually adds to the array and only replaces the existing string... so the array only ever has one string in it.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this?

```
data() {
      return {
        idArr: [],
      }
    },
    methods: {
      updateIdArr(show) {
        if (!this.idArr.includes(show._id)) {
          // add
          this.idArr.push(show._id);
        }
        var _this = this;
        this.$nextTick(() => {
                    delete _this.idArr[_this.idArr.findIndex(x => x.id === show._id)];
        })
     
      },
    }
}
```

Comment: the // remove line is not the problem, it works fine. The // add line with the push replaces instead of adding to the array. The array only ever has a single string in it no matter how many I push.